# Delphi Enterprise: how can I apply the Visitor Pattern without circular references?

Tags: delphi, oop, delphi-2009, visitor-pattern

With Delphi 2009 Enterprise I created code for the GoF Visitor Pattern in the model view, and separated the code in two units: one for the domain model classes, one for the visitor (because I might need other units for different visitor implementations, everything in one unit? '[Big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)' ahead!).

```
unit VisitorUnit;

interface

uses
  ConcreteElementUnit;

type
  IVisitor = interface;

  IElement = interface
  procedure Accept(AVisitor :IVisitor);
  end;

  IVisitor = interface
  procedure VisitTConcreteElement(AElement :TConcreteElement);
  end;

  TConcreteVisitor = class(TInterfacedObject, IVisitor)
  public
    procedure VisitTConcreteElement(AElement :TConcreteElement);
  end;

implementation

procedure TConcreteVisitor.VisitTConcreteElement(AElement :TConcreteElement);
begin
  { provide implementation here }
end;

end.
```

and the second unit for the business model classes

```
unit ConcreteElementUnit;

interface

uses
  VisitorUnit;

type
  TConcreteElement = class(TInterfacedObject, IElement)
  public
    procedure Accept(AVisitor :IVisitor); virtual;
  end;

  Class1 = class(TConcreteElement)
  public
    procedure Accept(AVisitor :IVisitor);
  end;

implementation

{ Class1 }

procedure Class1.Accept(AVisitor: IVisitor);
begin
  AVisitor.VisitTConcreteElement(Self);
end;

end.
```

See the problem? A circular unit reference. Is there an elegant solution? I guess it requires "n+1" additional units with base interface / base class definitions to avoid the CR problem, and tricks like hard casts?

Comment: I am still waiting for a comment like 'circular references are an indicator of bad design' :)

Comment: See also: http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/16/the-visitor-pattern-part-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following scheme to implement a flexible visitor pattern:

#### Declaration of base visitor types

```
unit uVisitorTypes;
type
  IVisited = interface
  { GUID }
    procedure Accept(Visitor: IInterface);
  end;

  IVisitor = interface
  { GUID }
    procedure Visit(Instance: IInterface);
  end;

  TVisitor = class(..., IVisitor)
    procedure Visit(Instance: IInterface);
  end;

procedure TVisitor.Visit(Instance: IInterface);
var
  visited: IVisited;
begin
  if Supports(Instance, IVisited, visited) then 
    visited.Accept(Self)
  else
    // raise exception or handle error elsewise    
end;
```

#### The unit for of the element class

```
unit uElement;

type
  TElement = class(..., IVisited)
    procedure Accept(Visitor: IInterface);
  end;

  // declare the visitor interface next to the class-to-be-visited declaration   
  IElementVisitor = interface
  { GUID }
    procedure VisitElement(Instance: TElement);
  end;

procedure TElement.Accept(Visitor: IInterface);
var
  elementVisitor: IElementVisitor;
begin
  if Supports(Visitor, IElementVisitor, elementVisitor) then
    elementVisitor.VisitElement(Self)
  else
    // if override call inherited, handle error or simply ignore
end;
```

#### The actual visitor implementation

```
unit MyVisitorImpl;

uses
  uVisitorTypes, uElement;

type
  TMyVisitor = class(TVisitor, IElementVisitor)
    procedure VisitElement(Instance: TElement);
  end;

procedure TMyVisitor.VisitElement(Instance: TElement);
begin
  // Do whatever you want with Instance 
end;
```

#### Calling the visitor

```
uses
  uElement, uMyElementVisitor;

var
  visitor: TMyVisitor;
  element: TElement;
begin
  // get hands on some element

  visitor := TMyVisitor.Create;
  try
    visitor.Visit(element);
  finally
    visitor.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not define IVisitor

```
IVisitor = interface
  procedure VisitElement(AElement :IElement);
end;
```

then TConcreteElement in its own unit :

```
unit ConcreteElementUnit;

interface

uses
  VisitorUnit;

type
  TConcreteElement = class(TInterfacedObject, IElement)
  public
    procedure Accept(AVisitor :IVisitor); virtual;
  end;

  Class1 = class(TConcreteElement)
  public
    procedure Accept(AVisitor :IVisitor);
  end;

implementation

{ Class1 }

procedure Class1.Accept(AVisitor: IVisitor);
begin
  AVisitor.VisitElement(Self);
end;

end.
```

That way you are not mixing class and interface references (always a bad idea)

Comment: In your VisitElement method, the argument is of type IElement, so the method body can only access methods and properties declared in IElement, but no properties or methods of TConcreteElement instances. A Visitor actually declares a method for every visited class type:  procedure VisitTConcreteElement1(AElement :TConcreteElement1), procedure VisitTConcreteElement2(AElement :TConcreteElement2), (...) VisitTConcreteElementN(AElement :TConcreteElementN)

Answer (score 1):

The following implementation using generic type on Visitor interface to solve the circular reference issue of `Visitor` pattern:

`Visitor.Intf.pas`:

```
unit Visitor.Intf;

interface

type
  IVisitor<T> = interface
    procedure Visit_Element(o: T);
  end;

implementation

end.
```

`Element.pas`:

```
unit Element;

interface

uses Visitor.Intf;

type
  TElement = class
    procedure Accept(const V: IVisitor<TElement>);
  end;

implementation

procedure TElement.Accept(const V: IVisitor<TElement>);
begin
  V.Visit_Element(Self);
end;

end.
```

`Visitor.Concrete.pas`:

```
unit Visitor.Concrete;

interface

uses Element, Visitor.Intf;

type
  TConcreteVisitor = class(TInterfacedObject, IVisitor<TElement>)
  protected
    procedure Visit_Element(o: TElement);
  end;

implementation

procedure TConcreteVisitor.Visit_Element(o: TElement);
begin
  // write implementation here
end;

end.
```

Using the TElement and TConcreteVisitor class:

```
var E: TElement;
begin
  E := TElement.Create;
  E.Accept(TConcreteVisitor.Create as IVisitor<TElement>);
  E.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Compiler error on line `E.Accept(TConcreteVisitor.Create as IVisitor<TElement>);`:  


    [DCC Error] Project1.dpr(16): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
Juste leav it as : `E.Accept(TConcreteVisitor.Create);`

Comment: @TridenT: I am using `XE4`, `XE5` and `XE6` to compile and no compiler error found at line `E.Accept(TConcreteVisitor.Create as IVisitor<TElement>)`

Comment: hum ... strange! I tested on XE6 and must delete the `as IVisitor<TElement>` part to compile.

Comment: @TridenT: That sounds strange.  I have double test my sample and it works without errors.

Answer (score 0):

The decleration of TConcreteElement shoud be in VisitorUnit (or a third unit)

or better

The IVisitator should be changed to:

```
 IVisitor = interface
  procedure VisitTConcreteElement(AElement :IElement);
 end;
```