# How to solve the CYCLIC relation issue between 2 or more Units in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm using 2 Units in Delphi 2010: **Unit1** has a Form with a `TEdit` and a `Button`, this `Button` will call a procedure from **Unit2** (**Unit2** doesn't have a form). That procedure will change the 'caption' property of the `TEdit` of **Unit1**, I tried to put **Unit2** in **Unit1** "Uses" to access the procedure, and put **Unit1** in the "Uses" of **Unit2** to to access the `TEdit` in **Unit1**, but this relation is cyclic.

I'm not sure what can I do to solve this, any suggestion?

Comment: do not tie GUI elements together and the problem wil solve itself. Work with objects and pass them between forms, the object can be defined in a separate unit that can be used by both forms...

Comment: Well, it can be done by moving the uses Unit1 clause to the implementation section of unit 2, but that is far from good practice. Unit 2 should really be organised so that is does not need to know about unit 1. For example, the procedure in unit 2 could be a function that returns a string which unit 1 will then assign to the caption property of unit1.

Comment: See [Delphi Enterprise: how can I apply the Visitor Pattern without circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2356318/576719)

Comment: Thank you guys for replying, I'll try your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, and which one is most appropriate depends crucially on the precise circumstances, so technically this question is too broad for Stack Overflow, I suspect.

## Method 1

Still, let me just show you one very simple approach. This might not be a good approach, but it is close to what it seems you are trying to do.

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Drop a `TButton` and a `TEdit` control on the main form (`TForm1` in `Unit1`).
3. Create a new unit, Unit2:

   ```
   unit Unit2;

   interface

   procedure SetCaption;

   implementation

   uses
     Unit1;

   procedure SetCaption;
   begin
     Unit1.Form1.Edit1.Text := 'Hello, World!';
   end;

   end.
   ```
4. On the main form, use this event handler for the button's `OnClick` event:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Unit2.SetCaption;
   end;
   ```

   after you have added `Unit2` to the `implementation` section's `uses` clause. In full,

   ```
   unit Unit1;

   interface

   uses
     Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
     Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

   type
     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       Button1: TButton;
       Edit1: TEdit;
       procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
     private
       { Private declarations }
     public
       { Public declarations }
     end;

   var
     Form1: TForm1;

   implementation

   uses
     Unit2;

   {$R *.dfm}

   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Unit2.SetCaption;
   end;

   end.
   ```

Notice how the units may use each other if referenced only in the implementation sections. Also notice we use the global `Form1` variable in `Unit1` to refer to the automatically created instance of `TForm1`. In many (most) cases, you don't want to use automatically created forms, but that is a different story (I could write a 100-page Delphi textbook here!).

## Method 2

Also, let me reiterate the fact that there are many other ways to accomplish this result. For instance, this is arguably a better approach:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Unit2.SetCaption(Edit1);
end;

end.



unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  StdCtrls;

procedure SetCaption(AEdit: TCustomEdit);

implementation

procedure SetCaption(AEdit: TCustomEdit);
begin
  AEdit.Text := 'Hello, World!';
end;

end.
```

## Method 3

Arguably even better:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := Unit2.GetText;
end;

end.



unit Unit2;

interface

function GetText: string;

implementation

function GetText: string;
begin
  Result := 'Hello, World!';
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and replies! I implemented them all and they just worked, which one do you suggest to use if I need to get elements like DataSetProviders, TSQLStoredProcs, TDataSource, etc.?

Comment: I don't know.  If I ever saw code like this `Unit1.Form1.Edit1.Text := 'Hello, World!';`, I would burn it out of the codebase with fire.  This is heading straight down the path to a spaghetti code nightmare.  I would never suggest anyone write code like this, even as an exercise.  Method 1 should be the example of how not to do it.  Ever.  `Form1` should be the only object that directly manipulates children or fields of `Form1`.  Other classes or units reaching inside should always be a huge red flag.

Comment: @J amen  to that! it all boils down to adhering to SOLID principle, RAD development encourages users to do the wrong thing...

Comment: I would personally go for somethin glike Option 2 or 3 becuase of SOLID coding principles.If tomorow I decide to use another type of Edit or change the name of the edit control I would only have to change that in one place and not everywhere the edit is referenced.

In the SetCaption of Option 2, I would also have a check to see if the AEdit parameter is assigned, otherwise it will result in an Access Violantion;